# invoking the virtual machine from java program

Tags: java, virtualization, xen

In my project, i have to start the virtual machine to xen hypervisor when the authentication is given by the client. So whenever user enter his credentials for virtual machine the java program has to initiate the virtual machine and the virtual machine will be avaialable to user..is that possible? if not with xen, is it possible either any one of the hyper visors? please help me. thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to use the the [Java bindings for libvirt](http://libvirt.org/java.html) which provide an interface for controlling a variety of virtualization solutions programatically.

It has specific documentation for Xen found: [here](http://libvirt.org/drvxen.html)

A quick review of [the API](http://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt.html) shows that once you have things configured correctly the function `virDomainCreate` to start your virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you sir,my project is to provide the authentication to users on cloud.As Eucalyptus has its own authentication, i can not use the eucalyptus.i would like to do with either xen hypervisor or xencloud platform as my cloud...and i am not sure which one to be used exactly..i have my system configuration as 4GB ram,intel i7 with 2.93GHz,320GB HD,1 NIC.. i will have this computer installed with xenhypervisor/xencloud as cloud and we create the Virtual machine(1 or many)and these VM works as clients, another different computer A which works as server.

Comment: if a user need the vm he will contact the server and server creates the vm  then client can use the vm...i think xen cloud also has the authentication mechanism...can we override this using any API....can we disable the xen authentication and create our own......is my system configuration sufficient? i can not have more than this configuration as i am student.....could you please tell me if you have any idea on this. thank you in advance..